# How can I get the "code" value from redirect url's response?

Tags: django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I wrote a function in order to get the **code** value from redirect url's response, however I cannot catch it.

the function;

```
def auth_for_app(request):

    CLIENT_ID = "xxx"
    CLIENT_SECRET = "xxx"

    REDIRECT_URI = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/auth'
    AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://www.example.com/admin/user/auth"
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.example.com/oauth/v2/token"
    STATE = "2b33fdd45jbevd6nam" # temporary state id

    request.GET.get('{}?client_id={}&response_type=code&state={}&redirect_uri={}'.format(AUTHORIZE_URL, CLIENT_ID, STATE, REDIRECT_URI))

    request.session['code'] = request.GET.get('code')
    code = request.session['code']

    print ("***AUTH START***")
    print (code)
    print ("***AUTH END***") 

    return render (request, 'products/auth.html')
```

I also wrote `print` that I can be sure that I am catching it. However I am getting this result;

```
***AUTH START***
None
***AUTH END***
```

**EDIT (added products/urls.py):**

products/urls.py;

```
app_name = 'products'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='base'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('auth/', views.auth_for_app, name='auth_for_app'),
]
```

Comment: Sorry, this code is very unclear. What is the point of that `request.GET.get...` line? It literally does nothing at all. Is a code being passed in the querystring of the URL that is requesting this view? Please show that URL.

Comment: I added URLs.. I think `request.GET.get...` line makes the request to the provider application in order to get the code and state parameters? @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood something here.

`request.GET` is the query that is passed to the view, via the `request` object that is the view function parameter. In other words, if the user went to `/auth/?foo=bar` then `request.GET get('foo')` would give the result "bar".

This doesn't make any request to other websites. For that you need something completely different - a third-party library called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Despite the similarity in names these have nothing to do with each other. You need to install requests, import it in your views file, call it, and do something with the response:

```
import requests
...
response = requests.get(AUTHORIZE_URL, params={"client_id": CLIENT_ID, "response_type": "code", "state": STATE, "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI})
code = response.json()['code']
```

Comment: I changed it as you wrote here but I am getting this error: `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

Comment: So clearly that API does not return JSON. But you have not given any details of what it actually is so that we know what it does return.